# How to use high priority patch in dmenu

Tags: dmenu

I am trying to use this patch in dmenu

https://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/patches/highpriority/

I have the patch installed but I can not figure out how to set hp (the list of items to be considered high priority ), what does a "flag" mean in this context (I do not know C )

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for such a late response. I was searching for a answer a minute ago too.
It turns out it is easy. You need to pass it as a input arg when calling for dmenu like:

```
dmenu_run -hp pcmanfm,lf,st,code
```

or:

```
dmenu_run -hp $(cat hpList)
```